# Migrating from register.com webmail

Tags: email, migration

Anyone know of any tools to migrate emails from register.com's webmail to anything else (gmail, local mbox, anything!), I have nearly 15 years of mails and folders I want to keep.

Other than spending ages writing some Perl scraper code I wondered if anyone else had already done this.
sorry - It's impossible to search Google for the name of a registrar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like even the basic service allows POP3 access to your email. So you should be able to configure an email client such as [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://getthunderbird.com) to download your email.  The configuration settings are found in [the FAQ](http://help.register.com/cgi-bin/register_help.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=3110):

> In addition to the username, password,
>   and matching email address*, the
>   following settings are needed when
>   configuring a 3rd party email client:
>
> **POP Settings:**
>
> Incoming POP3 mail server:
>   mail.exampledomain.com
>
> Secure Password Authentication: NO
>
> Incoming POP3 port number: 110

You may also want to remember to check the *Leave Messages on Server* box so that you don't lose all of your mail from your web-mail interface.

Comment: The pop interface only lets you new email or your inbox - not your folders.

Comment: Ok - they now have imap and you can access all the folders.

Comment: So I can just use any old IMAP downloader